# How to remove duplicate phrases from list of dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have the following method, it takes a list of dicts and returns a new list which contains only dicts with unique `phrases`

```
@staticmethod
def remove_duplicate_phrases(words: List[Dict[str, Any]]):
    unique_phrases, unique_words = set(), []
    for word in words:
        if word['phrase'] not in unique_phrases:
            unique_phrases.add(word['phrase'])
            unique_words.append(word)
    return unique_words
```

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Could you show how you run it and explain why you think it's slow?

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest way I usually opt for:

```
>>> list_ = [
    {"phrase": 1},
    {"phrase": 1},
    {"phrase": 2},
    {"phrase": None}
]

>>> list(set([dict_['phrase'] for dict_ in words]))
[1, 2, None]
```

The above is an example of how you can clean up a list of dictionaries, although the performance is not going to improve substantially; the solution depends on the number of words you're passing too.

`set()` is beneficial in such cases where you want an **unordered** unique collection of elements.

Running the solution in this answer and yours in comparison on approx. 2000 elements and 3 times resulted that the solution in this answer is slightly faster.

```
# solution in answer
0.001382553018629551

# your solution
0.002490615996066481
```